# How can I get an empty collection of the same type as a given instance?

Tags: scala, reflection, constructor

As part of a rewriting mechanism, I need to obtain and execute a collection constructor of the same type as a given instance. The code below summarizes my attempt.

```scala
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag
def getEmptyCollection[N : TypeTag](collection: N): N = {
  val runtime = scala.reflect.runtime.universe
  val mirror = runtime.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
  val classSymbol = runtime.typeOf[N].typeSymbol.asClass
  val classMirror = mirror.reflectClass(classSymbol)
  val constructorSymbol = runtime.typeOf[N].decl(runtime.termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod
  val constructorMirror = classMirror.reflectConstructor(constructorSymbol)
  constructorMirror()
}

val emptyList: List[Int] = getEmptyCollection(List(1, 2, 3))
```

This code, though, produces an instantiation exception:
java.lang.InstantiationException was thrown

Perhaps "typeOf[N]" is the problem, but I'm just guessing. Would you know what the problem might be?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

The correct way (in Scala 2.12, probably somewhat different in 2.13 while 2.11 will need explicit type parameters):

```
import scala.collection.generic.GenericTraversableTemplate
import scala.collection.GenTraversable

def getEmptyCollection[A, CC[X] <: GenericTraversableTemplate[X, CC] with GenTraversable[X]](collection: CC[A]) = 
  collection.genericBuilder[A].result()

println(getEmptyCollection(List(1, 2))) // List()
println(getEmptyCollection(Vector(1, 2))) // Vector()
```

No reflection required!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Alexey. Looks like this copes well with the companion objects of the generic collections. It doesn't work with Option, however. And, of course, it is not a collection but can be used homogeneously in many cases (for example, with map method). Would you see a solution that could also fit Option and recursively defined collections (like List(List()))? Regards.

Comment: 1. I expect in Scala 2.13 the equivalent should work with `Option` since it extends Iterable now. "And, of course, it is not a collection but can be used homogeneously in many cases (for example, with map method)." It isn't really homogenous. They are different methods which happen to have the same name. 2. For `List[List[Int]]`, if you want an empty collection it's still `List()`, `List(List())` has a single element.